# Update RecyclerView hidden items

Tags: java, android

I have a RecyclerView with a list of items that can be updated according to background events.

To update a single item I use `notifyItemChanged`, every item of the list has a precise `itemId` as tag, so I can get their relative position to update them.
Here the code:

```
for (int position = 0; position <= recyclerView.getChildCount(); position++) {
   final View view = recyclerView.getChildAt(position);
      if (view != null) {
          final String viewTag = view.getTag().toString();
          if (viewTag.equals(itemId)) {
              LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = ((LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager());
              final int firstVisiblePosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
              final int realPosition = position + firstVisiblePosition;
              recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(realPosition );
              break;
    }
  }
}
```

This works only for visible items, so if the user scrolls the list, the new visible items are not correctly updated.
If I set:

```
holder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

everything works, but I lose the smoothness of the RecyclerView.

Is there a way to update hidden items?